# MySQL 5.5 Case incorrect syntax

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

Hey I can't get this case statement to work, would someone mind telling what is wrong with the syntax is.

```
SELECT standards.standard_id, standards.title, standards.level,standards.credits, SUM(standards.credits), standards.assessment 

CASE  WHEN standards.assessment = 1 THEN 'External' ELSE 'Internal' END CASE
FROM standards JOIN courses_standards ON standards.standard_id = courses_standards.standard_id 
WHERE courses_standards.course_id = 1
```

The exact error is:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN standards.assessment = 1 THEN 'External' ELSE 'Internal' END CASE FR' at line 3

Comment: These are basic errors. You're missing a comma,  case is a reserved word, no group by clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a syntax error with how you're ending your case. You need to provide an Alias for when you end the case.

```
SELECT standards.standard_id, standards.title, standards.level,standards.credits, SUM(    standards.credits), standards.assessment, 

CASE  WHEN standards.assessment = 1 THEN 'External' ELSE 'Internal' END assessment
FROM standards JOIN courses_standards ON standards.standard_id = courses_standards.    standard_id 
WHERE courses_standards.course_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You've missed a comma between `standards.assessment` and `CASE`